# Building a string (or char) array - newbie

Tags: esp32

I pretty new to this and have only been doing it for a few week. Although I have programmed in other languages my understanding of declaring the types, converting types and pointers is still pretty week. I tried all day yesterday to try to get this code to work but couldn't!

I need a array (of char or string) to hold lockout info and then be able to pass it to the email function as a string. If I get one part to work it breaks the next part. The current version of code look like this:

```c++
char lockDetail [10][250];

String ts =  timeStamp();
char reason [] = "Invalid login attemp " + ts + "other stuff I want to append";
strncpy(lockDetail [lockCount], reason, sizeof(reason) );
.
.
.
String msg = lockDetail [0] + "<p>" + lockDetail [1] + "<p>" + lockDetail [2];
sendMessage (subject, msg);
```

I updated my code as per jcaron suggestions, now I'm having the same issue I originally had - when called it crashes/reboots the ESP32.

**UPDATED CODE:**

```c++
String lockDetail [2];
int lockCount = 0;
String ts =  timeStamp();
String reason = "Invalid login attemp " + ts + "other stuff I want to append";
lockDetail[lockCount] = String(reason);
.
.
String msg = lockDetail [0] + "<p>" + lockDetail [1] + "<p>" + lockDetail [2];
```

On further investigation the crash happens when I call the sendMessage function  with msg = to msg above, which includes the lockDetail array. I'm using [mobizt/ESP-Mail-Client library](https://github.com/mobizt/ESP-Mail-Client)

```c++
void sendMessage(const char* subject, String msg)
```

so crash:  `String msg = lockDetail [0] + "<p>" + lockDetail [1] + "<p>" + lockDetail [2];`

no crash: `sendMessage ("subject", "My Message");`

Not sure if this helps (it is above my current level).
This is from the **mail library example** (and used in my code as well).
Wondering if the .c_str() part is having a problem with the array (but now isnt msg that we created just a plain old normal string?)

```c++
String msg = "the message"; 
message.html.content = msg.c_str();
```

More help appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: you are asking in the wrong place ... your question is about programming, not about IoT ... it's like asking at a house construction site `how to cut down a tree?` because you want to build a house from the wood

Comment: You have a weird mix of C-style and OO-style code. You should probably pick one or the other. Also, if you don’t have access to a proper debugger (may be tricky with an ESP32), just print every intermediate value. I’m pretty sure you’ll notice the result is very different from what you expect.

Comment: Actually, that doesn't even compile. Don't mix `String`s (which are objects, can be concatenated with `+`) and character arrays (which are not objects, and you can't add using `+`).

Comment: Will post in more appropriate place in future, sorry. Code is a mess/mix of styles because I have been cut/pasting stuff for hours in desperation to get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you are mixing C-style strings (character arrays) and C++-style strings (objects), and that gives weird results.

In the Arduino environment, unless you know what you are doing, you probably want to using the C++-style `String` object rather than C-style `char[]` strings.

> ```cpp
> char lockDetail [10][250];
> ```

You are defining a 2D array (which also has a fixed size, which can raise many issues). Instead, define an array of `String` objects:

```cpp
String lockDetail[10];
```

> ```cpp
> char reason [] = "Invalid login attemp " + ts + "other stuff I want to append";
> ```

You are creating a string object by concatenating several of them, but then trying to assign that to a C-style string (won't work) which in addition requires a static initialiser so that the size of the string can be computed (at the very least `ts` is not constant, won't work). Instead, create a `String` object:

```cpp
String reason = "Invalid login attemp " + ts + "other stuff I want to append";
```

> ```cpp
> strncpy(lockDetail [lockCount], reason, sizeof(reason) );
> ```

You're copying a C-style string into another. Note that even if `sizeof(reason)` had a proper value, it's not the one you're supposed to use with `strncpy`: you should use the size of the **destination** buffer, not the source one (the length of the source string is defined by the terminating nul).

But since we switched to string objects (which you can't use `strncpy` on), let's just make a copy instead (note that depending on your actual code it is probably not even needed to make a copy):

```cpp
lockDetail[lockCount] = String(reason);
```

> ```cpp
> String msg = lockDetail [0] + "<p>" + lockDetail [1] + "<p>" + lockDetail [2];
> ```

This couldn't work because `lockDetail[0]` was a C-style string (actually, a `char [250]`) and `"<p>"` in this context another C-style string (actually, a `const char [4]`), and ditto for the rest. You can't add those. But now that we have switched everybody to `String` objects, it'll work.

Comment: I have changed my code to reflect your suggestions (it is much closer to the original code I wrote), but it is having the same issue  I originally had - when called it crashes/reboots the ESP32.  The line that is causing the reboot is 'lockDetail[lockCount] = String(reason);'.  It is needed because the whole purpose is to build the array lockDetail [x]. More help appreciated.

Comment: @user15837 Please edit your original question and **add** an update with your new code. Note that in the code you have us, there's nothing that declares or initialises `lockCount` so we have no idea what the value of that is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was passing the email message the last element of the array which is null. That was causing the crash.